# I can't import the configuration on production servers

Tags: database, 9, importing-exporting

I am unable to uninstall the MySQL module. I can't import the configuration on production servers when I upgrade Drupal from 9.3.x to 9.4.x.

I get the following error.

> The import failed due to the following reasons:
> Unable to uninstall the MySQL module because: The module 'MySQL' is providing the database driver 'mysql'
> Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporterException: There were errors validating the config synchronization.
> Unable to uninstall the MySQL module because: The module 'MySQL' is providing the database driver 'mysql'.. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigImporter->validate() (line 756 of /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigImporter.php)

Comment: I found the Drupal module for MariaDB https://www.drupal.org/project/mysql56. I don't think so. This is not the Right solution. also the module isn't stable.

Comment: Sounds like incorrect deployment order, you either have missed or executed *updatedb* too late. This blog might help: https://agaric.coop/blog/drupal-94-installation-existing-configuration-fails-because-unable-uninstall-mysql-module

Comment: It's depends on the Driver version. 
If using Drupal 9 with MySQL or Percona, version 5.7.8+ is required.
If using Drupal 9 with MariaDB, version 10.3.7+ is required.
If using Drupal 9 with SQLite, version 3.26+ is required. (PHP 7.4 does not use the system provided SQLite, so take extra care to make sure your PHP is compiled with at least this version).
If using Drupal 9 with PostgreSQL, version 10 is required with the pg_trgm extension.

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade process recommended by drupal: update of drupal/core with-dependencies, db update with drush them cache rebuild

https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer

Comment: @dickwan & Hudri Thank you so much. I resolved it now. It's related to missing module from Production server. I took the DB from Production server, then I export those configurations then I did the deployment again with my missing module.